# Text File Sum of Specific Columns PHP

Tags: php, text-files, calculated-columns

I have a txt file populated with line of numbers... I have a code wherein the user can filter particular lines in the txt file

CODE for FILTERING:

```
<?php
$file = 'upload/filter.txt';
$searchfor = $_POST['search'];
$btn = $_POST['button'];
$sum = 0;

if($btn == 'search') {

//prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
 $contents = file_get_contents($file);

// escape special characters in the query
 $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";


// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
echo "Found matches:\n";
echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
 }
else{
echo "No matches found";
 }

 }
 ?>
```

for example the result of the filtering will now produce 4 lines out of 1,000,000 lines from the text file

0100002291310106200140001020055460000000001000000072860103508104
0100002291320106200140001020055460000000005000000072860103508101
0100002291330106200140001020055460000000001000000072860103508102
0100002291340106200140001020055460000000005000000072860103508109

i need a code that will select only particular column and add them together using PHP code... example i only want to add columns 1-10 so the structure will look like this from the lines given above

sructure:

0100002291 
0100002291 
0100002291

Please Help

Comment: You want to post-process resulted strings? (in case that user input will match at position above 10, for example)

Comment: I think its easy to iterate `$matches[0]` and use `substr($match, 0,9)`

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Thanks for relpying sir... Ahmmm I just need to know how to select range of columns ex: (1-20, 1-30) and add that columns only from top to bottom of the line

Comment: @Akam will substr() get the sum of the specified columns?

Comment: `substr('0100002291310106200140001020055460000000001000000072860103508104', 0, 9)=0100002291`

Comment: @Bongsky what do you mean 'column', by the way? It seems it's just characters, so `substr` will fit.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo There are 65 digits in a line... now i just need to get the 1st to ten digits of each line and add them from top to bottom

Comment: Thanks for all the response... I already got it ^_^